# Idiom to construct a URI with a query string in Elixir

Tags: elixir, uri, query-string

I'm wondering what the most idiomatic way is to use `URI` to add a query string to a base URI in Elixir.

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
iex(1)> base = "http://example.com/endpoint"
"http://example.com/endpoint"

iex(2)> query_string = URI.encode_query(foo: "bar")
"foo=bar"

iex(3)> uri_string = URI.parse(base) |> Map.put(:query, query_string) |> URI.to_string
"http://example.com/endpoint?foo=bar"
```

But was wondering if there is a cleaner way to set the query string. I know about [`URI.merge/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/URI.html#merge/2), but I don't think a query string is a valid URI, so that's probably not approriate here (the `?` will not be added).

I could also do something like:

```
uri_string = %URI{ URI.parse(base) | query: query_string } |> URI.to_string
```

But I'm wondering if there is a simpler or clearer method I've missed.

Answer (score 17):

I think your first example, with some formatting, reads pretty well:

```
uri_string =
  base_url
  |> URI.parse()
  |> Map.put(:query, URI.encode_query(params))
  |> URI.to_string()
```

I'm not aware of other idioms/shortcuts.

Answer (score 6):

Elixir 1.13 introduced [`URI.new!/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/URI.html#new!/1), which unlike [`URI.parse/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/URI.html#parse/1) also validates the URI. Elixir 1.14 introduced [`URI.append_query/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/URI.html#append_query/2) for conveniently updating the query string. For Elixir 1.14 and greater, I think the most idiomatic way to do this is:

```elixir
"http://example.com/endpoint"
|> URI.new!()
|> URI.append_query(URI.encode_query(foo: "bar"))
|> URI.to_string()
```

Output:

```elixir
"http://example.com/endpoint?foo=bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that it's more idiomatic but you can do simple string interpolation if you know the string you're trying to build.

```
uri_string = "#{base}?#{query_string}"
```

Comment: On empty `query_string` this code adds a redundant trailing question mark :(