# How get request HTTPPoison sending a query string

Tags: elixir, httpoison

I need get in the api by passing a query string in case the route is:

```
api/v1/servers/#{server_name}/zones
```

Query params is `rrsets=false` and code:

```
HTTPoison.get!("api/v1/servers/#{server_name}/zones")
```

How I send with a query string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in your question doesn't even compile - please put more effort to provide a working example next time.

[`HTTPoison.get!/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/httpoison/HTTPoison.html#get!/3) accepts a URL as its first argument, so you can just provide the query string as part of the URL:

```elixir
HTTPoison.get!("api/v1/servers/#{server_name}/zones?rrsets=false")
```

If you want to build URL with a dynamic query string, see [Idiom to construct a URI with a query string in Elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508509/idiom-to-construct-a-uri-with-a-query-string-in-elixir):

```elixir
"api/v1/servers/#{server_name}/zones"
|> URI.parse()
|> Map.put(:query, URI.encode_query(rrsets: false))
|> URI.to_string()
```